# Multisig wallet generating a big number of ETH addresses

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets, mist, multisignature

I'm looking for a possibility to generate many (say, 1000) addresses from a multisig wallet. The idea is that we accept payments to these addresses, and then move all funds to a single address using 2-of-3 signatures. Is it possible?

I know how to generate multiple addresses with geth API, but whoever knows the geth's passphrase, owns all funds, since this is not a multisig wallet.

I know I can use e.g. Mist for multisig, but this implies we have a single multisig wallet that has all funds, and we have 1000's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A multisig wallet is just a contract. You can just deploy the contract 1000s of times to produce 1000s of multisig wallets.

Comment: And then the signatories will have to sign 1000 transactions to send all funds to one destination, right?

Comment: Yes. I thought that's what you wanted.